# How do I create erc4337 based smart contracts with custom rules using safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, erc-4337, account-abstraction

My goal is to create an application that has a good UI and allows users to create ERC4337 wallets with specific rules.

Currenlty, I am using web3auth to allow users to log in and get a pub/pvt key pair.
The next step is to generate a smart contract that uses the address as the owner and allows users to specify any rules like multisig, spending limit, time based logic etc.

I think the best way to do this is to use safe protocol SDK and add more modules based on functions. But I don't know how to implement this. How do I add features to smart contract?

The problem is how do I create this contract? How do I modify/use safe contracts to have custom rules for different users?